# Change the class of the preceding element

Tags: jquery

Here's the structure of my code. I need to change the class of the h3 tag before a div in jquery, for example I need to change the class of the h3 class above the div with an ID of "firstCol".

```
‹h3 class="class123"› ‹a href="#"› First Column ‹/a›  ‹/h3 ›

‹div id="firstCol" class="myStyle"› Content Here ‹/div ›

‹h3 class="class123">‹a href="#"›First Column‹/h3›

‹div id="secondCol" class="myStyle"›Content Here‹/div›
```

Can someone help me please..

Comment: I'm sorry this isn't so directly helpful, but that seems like a weird way of declaring the HTML. Shouldn't both the `h3` and `div` be part of the "column" declaration? You could add a "content" class next to "myStyle" to be able to easily select it and add/change content. If you are not allowed to modify the HTML, or disagree, I guess my suggestion can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single function to change a class, but you can remove the previous one and add your new one:

```
$('#firstCol').prev('h3').removeClass().addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
$('#firstCol').prev().addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the class of the element before the div...

```
$('#firstCol').prev().attr("class", "new-class");
```

There are ways to remove, add and toggle classes, but that will remove all classes and add a new one.